# aws glue s3 target - creating partitions of 20 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

By default when I read two three records also from dynamo DB source and target is s3, even then its creating 20 partition files in target and only two are having data and other are empty files.

How can we control this file creation?

Or limit number of records in each file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the number of files by changing the number of partitions. First, you will need to change your DynamicFrame to spark DataFrame, then change the number of partitions and finally back to a DynamicFrame:

```
dataframe = DynamicFrame.toDF(applymapping3).repartition(2) #where 2 is the number of files/partitions.
dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataframe, glueContext, "dynamicframe")
```

Similar way, if you want to limit by number of records, you can do something like:

```
n_partitions = int(math.ceil(dataframe.count() / float(file_size))) #where file_size can be 500 records.
dataframe1 = DynamicFrame.toDF(dataframe).repartition(n_partitions)
```

Comment: You will also need to add in the following import at the start of the job script for this to work: `from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame`